# What is the permission needed for certain phones to display Shortcut badges?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I have added [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) in my app and it works fine with most phones.

But I have a problem with **Vivo** & **Oppo** phones it seems theyre not showing it even though the lib is showing it is supported.

Does anyone know the permission needed for these phones? 
Like in sony they used below permission to allow it.

```
 <!-- Sony -->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" />
```

Comment: Permissions are already included automatically by the library. See https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/blob/master/ShortcutBadger/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: BTW You've opened an issue https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/254 but there was already another one open https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/issues/243

Comment: ah yes, its because theres no updates on the previous

Comment: @XavierRubioJansana do we have permission needed for vivo? beacuse right now facebook and whatsapp are showing even settings.

Comment: Last, the badges depend on the specific launcher. Have you checked if the launcher has changed (i.e. platform default launcher has changed lately)?

Comment: I saw the launcher is using `com.bbk.launcher2` in Vivo phone.

Comment: In the manifest there is a permission labeled as "Oppo", but I do not have experience with this devices.

Comment: yes but still doesnt show, Well ShortcutBadger did write on their supported launchers that it isnt fully supported.

Comment: Clarifying on these 2 phones, Facebook & Whatsapp shown badges on these 2 phones, While my app doesnt.

Comment: You can always try to check what FB is doing by analyzing the APK, and checking the permissions they are declaring in the manifest. Look for "facebook download apk" and open it using "Analyze APK" command in Android Studio.

Comment: great idea., Never thought of it though. haha your the best bud.

Comment: Hey I checked in facebook manfiest but sadly I also have the same in manifest. Is it possible that facebook harcoded it in the app to show notification badge regardless of what device? 

And also is it necessary to show runtime permission for notification badges?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I guess there's some kind of quirk in this platform and they worked around it, but I don't even have a device, so I cannot imagine how.